# How To Select The Value From XML Field in Oracle query

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have XML data from one of my table columns for which sample XML format is as mentioned below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Big5"?>
<SN Name="Group Medical Member Setup">
  <DO Name="datPrlMmr" Label="" Table="COMPRLMMR">
    <RECORD>
      <ACTION Name="M">
    <F Name="MMRCNYOFRSN" Label="" OldValue="HKG" NewValue="AUS" />
    <F Name="MDFBY" Label=" " OldValue="fc" NewValue="admin" />
    <F Name="MDFTMSTP" Label=" " OldValue="Thu Feb 19 11:14:37 HKT 2004" NewValue="Tue May 07 14:24:09 HKT 2019" />
      </ACTION>
    </RECORD>
  </DO>
  <DO Name="doAdmGMPlyMmrDtl" Label="" Table="ADMGMPLYMMRDTL">
    <RECORD>
      <ACTION Name="M">
    <F Name="MDFTMSTP" Label="Modified TimeStamp" OldValue="Mon May 06 03:12:20 SGT 2019" NewValue="Mon May 06 03:15:00 SGT 2019" />
    <F Name="RCDTMSTP" Label="Record TimeStamp" OldValue="Mon May 06 03:12:20 SGT 2019" NewValue="Mon May 06 03:15:00 SGT 2019" />
      </ACTION>
    </RECORD>
  </DO>
</SN>
```

I want to extract the value corresponding to `'NewValue'` tagname for the field `Name="MMRCNYOFRSN"`. This will appear only once in the XML. How can I extract the `NewValue` (AUS) through the SQL Query for Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you only want a single (attribute) value you can also do this with [XMLQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/XMLQUERY.html):

```
-- CTE for your sample data
with your_table (your_column) as (
  select xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Big5"?>
<SN Name="Group Medical Member Setup">
  <DO Name="datPrlMmr" Label="" Table="COMPRLMMR">
    <RECORD>
      <ACTION Name="M">
    <F Name="MMRCNYOFRSN" Label="" OldValue="HKG" NewValue="AUS" />
    <F Name="MDFBY" Label=" " OldValue="fc" NewValue="admin" />
    <F Name="MDFTMSTP" Label=" " OldValue="Thu Feb 19 11:14:37 HKT 2004" NewValue="Tue May 07 14:24:09 HKT 2019" />
      </ACTION>
    </RECORD>
  </DO>
  <DO Name="doAdmGMPlyMmrDtl" Label="" Table="ADMGMPLYMMRDTL">
    <RECORD>
      <ACTION Name="M">
    <F Name="MDFTMSTP" Label="Modified TimeStamp" OldValue="Mon May 06 03:12:20 SGT 2019" NewValue="Mon May 06 03:15:00 SGT 2019" />
    <F Name="RCDTMSTP" Label="Record TimeStamp" OldValue="Mon May 06 03:12:20 SGT 2019" NewValue="Mon May 06 03:15:00 SGT 2019" />
      </ACTION>
    </RECORD>
  </DO>
</SN>')
  from dual
)
-- actual query
select xmlquery('/SN/DO/RECORD/ACTION/F[@Name="MMRCNYOFRSN"]/@NewValue'
  passing t.your_column
  returning content) as MMRCNYOFRSN
from your_table t;

MMRCNYOFRSN                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AUS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with s as 
(select xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Big5"?>
<SN Name="Group Medical Member Setup">
  <DO Name="datPrlMmr" Label="" Table="COMPRLMMR">
    <RECORD>
      <ACTION Name="M">
    <F Name="MMRCNYOFRSN" Label="" OldValue="HKG" NewValue="AUS" />
    <F Name="MDFBY" Label=" " OldValue="fc" NewValue="admin" />
    <F Name="MDFTMSTP" Label=" " OldValue="Thu Feb 19 11:14:37 HKT 2004" NewValue="Tue May 07 14:24:09 HKT 2019" />
      </ACTION>
    </RECORD>
  </DO>
  <DO Name="doAdmGMPlyMmrDtl" Label="" Table="ADMGMPLYMMRDTL">
    <RECORD>
      <ACTION Name="M">
    <F Name="MDFTMSTP" Label="Modified TimeStamp" OldValue="Mon May 06 03:12:20 SGT 2019" NewValue="Mon May 06 03:15:00 SGT 2019" />
    <F Name="RCDTMSTP" Label="Record TimeStamp" OldValue="Mon May 06 03:12:20 SGT 2019" NewValue="Mon May 06 03:15:00 SGT 2019" />
      </ACTION>
    </RECORD>
  </DO>
</SN>') x from dual)
select t.*
from s,
xmltable(
'/SN/DO/RECORD/ACTION/F[@Name="MMRCNYOFRSN"]'
passing s.x
columns
name     varchar2(100) path '@Name',
oldvalue varchar2(100) path '@OldValue',
newvalue varchar2(100) path '@NewValue'
)(+) t;

NAME            OLDVALUE        NEWVALUE       
--------------- --------------- ---------------
MMRCNYOFRSN     HKG             AUS
```